# Azure load balancing VM's using Resource Manager

Tags: load-balancing, azure, cloud

With Azure Classic, I could create two VM's in the same cloud service and I would get one public IP for both, and it would automatically load balance traffic between the two VM's.

With the new Azure Resource Manager, I have no option to join a VM to a cloud service for obvious reasons. However, I still need to get one public IP for both VM's and have the traffic load balanced.

I saw that there is the [Azure Load Balancer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/) feature. Is this basically the replacement for the old cloud service load balancing? If so, does it cost anything to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/load-balancer/) page

> Azure Load Balancer is free of charge but not offered with Basic Virtual machines.

Even in the old cloud service model you needed to attach a load balancer to the underlying VIP, and then wire up the associated VMs

Load balancing under ARM puts a load balancer out in front of the IAAS machines, in a more logical way, that is more in keeping with standard networking practices.

(Although I have read in a few places now that ARM cloud services are coming - this is marked as 'planned' by the Azure team on the [azure](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/7899432-add-cloud-services-as-an-available-resource-when-w) feedback site. - It also seems it is possible to deploy Cloud services into ARM setups through the portal)

Comment: Interesting...can you link any reference stating that cloud services are coming to ARM? Seems like the whole point of ARM was to use resource groups vs cloud services, wouldn't make sense for them to re-introduce the same thing.

Comment: @blizz I have edited the answer